# Excel - Cannot figure out way to get excel to XML with current strutcure

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have my data set up as so:

```
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|               Old URL              |                 New URL            |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-a     |       http://newsite.com/page-a    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-b     |       http://newsite.com/page-a    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-c     |       http://newsite.com/page-b    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-d     |       http://newsite.com/page-c    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-e     |       http://newsite.com/page-c    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-f     |       http://newsite.com/page-c    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-g     |       http://newsite.com/page-c    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-h     |       http://newsite.com/page-d    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|      http://example.com/page-i     |       http://newsite.com/page-d    |
|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|
```

I need to get this data into an XML format as shown:

```
<urls>
  <url>
    <old>http://example.com/page-a</old>
    <old>http://example.com/page-b</old>
    <new>http://newsite.com/page-a</new>
  </url>
  <url>
    <old>http://example.com/page-c</old>
    <new>http://newsite.com/page-b</new>
  </url>
  <url>
    <old>http://example.com/page-d</old>
    <old>http://example.com/page-e</old>
    <old>http://example.com/page-f</old>
    <old>http://example.com/page-g</old>
    <new>http://newsite.com/page-c</new>
  </url>
  <url>
    <old>http://example.com/page-h</old>
    <old>http://example.com/page-i</old>
    <new>http://newsite.com/page-d</new>
  </url>
</urls>
```

Each `<url></url>` would be a row essentially be a new row. If I could have a `<url>` just for each single old URL to new URL, then this wouldn't be an issue. However, I have varying numbers of `<old></old>` for each `<new></new>`. In my head the only way I could think to do this was to have multiple columns of old and transpose the date from rows into columns, but this seems like it would take AGES. I have tens of thousands to do. Is anyone else aware of a better way to do this?

Comment: You only need one logical loop I think. Create a `Scripting.Dictionary` using the new URL string as the key, then the Item for that key is a comma separated list of old URLs. To build your XML then, create a `<url></url>` for each key and (using `Split`) separate the `Dictionary.Item` into the individual old URLs, creating the XML entries for them.

Comment: Your example is not clear. How do the old and new url match? Without knowing the pattern, we cannot help set up a logic routine.